# Find out number of numbers present in a comma separated string of numbers in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement to check if some given numbers are Pythogorean triplets.

The textbox accepts string of numbers in the below format:

3,4,5 (comma separated values)

If the user enters more than or three numbers an error alert is displayed. My team mate figure out a way to do this , but accidentally. How does the below method work?

```
    function CheckNumbers(strnum){
     var num = strnum.split(",")
     if(num.length != 3)
      {
        alert(Enter exactly three numbers!)
        return;

      }
    }
```

Should'nt it return the length of the string rather than the number of numbers?

Comment: It is working exactly as it should. Here is the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: `strnum.split(",")` will return an array, so calling `.length` on an array will return the number of items

Comment: 3,4,5 is a String?

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón yes it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read it, the input parameter strnum gets split by "," into an array, and num.length returns the length of the array.

Answer (score 0):

No, The above code is right what it does is to break string in to an array and than return the length of that array

```
strnum  = 1,2,3;
num = strnum.split(",") // num = [1,2,3]
num.length // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your case is you are using a Number, and replace is associated to String.
Try to cast it before.

```
strnum  = "1,2,3";
    num = strnum.split(",") // num = [1,2,3]
    num.length // 3
```